# clickable text in form of email + custom alert view

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I want in my app that email id is written in text form off-course, but that text should be clickable. And on clicking that a pop up should appear having two fields and two buttons. The two fields should be editable so as to type "from" and "message body" into it.The two buttons are of send and cancel.
please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just create button with your Email Address and set selector on it like bellow...

```
UIButton *BtnEmail = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[BtnEmail setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
[BtnEmail setTitle:@"YourEmailId" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
BtnEmail.frame = CGRectMake(85, 100, 150, 39 );/// set your frame
[BtnEmail addTarget:self action:@selector(EmailButtonClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[self.view addSubview:BtnEmail];
```

and in action event (Method) write this code.. and just add these two delegate in `.h` file `MFMessageComposeViewControllerDelegate` and `MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate` and also 1 framework name is  `MessageUI.framework`

```
-(IBAction)EmailButtonClicked:(id)sender{

        if ([MFMailComposeViewController canSendMail]) {
            appDelegate.imgCapture = [self captureView];
            [appDelegate.imgCapture retain];
            MFMailComposeViewController *mailComposeViewController = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
            NSString *mailBody = @"Set Your Body Message";


            [mailComposeViewController setMessageBody:mailBody isHTML:NO];
            mailComposeViewController.mailComposeDelegate = self;
            [self presentViewController:mailComposeViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
        } else {
            UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"e-Mail Sending Alert"
                                                            message:@"You can't send a mail"
                                                           delegate:nil
                                                  cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" 
                                                  otherButtonTitles:nil];
            [alert show];
            [alert release];
        }
}
```

and these bellow method is Delegate method..

```
#pragma mark - MFMessage Delegate

- (void)messageComposeViewController:(MFMessageComposeViewController *)controller didFinishWithResult:(MessageComposeResult)result
{
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}

- (void)mailComposeController:(MFMailComposeViewController*)controller didFinishWithResult:(MFMailComposeResult)result error:(NSError*)error
{
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

i hope this help you...